# ACF How to update a single field in a query

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I need to update a radio field for the specific post only when the condition meets (purchased and used values gets equal) as per the below code. Instead this updates the radio selection on all the posts. Need help to solve this.

If there is any other alternative method I can use to meet this requirement, please mention that too.

```
<?php

function expired() {
  echo "Expired";
}

function rto_deactivation() {
  $post_id = false;
  update_field('field_59ba2159ddd3b', 'Deactive', $post_id);
}

// Issue on function rto_deactivation(), when calls all RTOs get deactivated

$i=1;
$args = array(
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'post_type'   => 'rto_providers',
  'meta_key'    => 'package',
  'meta_value'  => 'Casual RTO'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>

  <div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>RTO Name</th>
        <th>Email Address</th>
        <th>Purchased</th>
        <th>Used</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

  <?php 
  while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
  $email_id = get_field( 'email_address', $post_id );
  $number_of_enquiries = get_field( 'number_of_enquiries', $post_id );
  $account_activation = get_field( 'account_activation', $post_id );
  ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $i++; ?></td>
      <td><?php the_title(); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $email_id; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $number_of_enquiries; ?></td>

      <?php
      $used = $wpdb->get_var(" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE form_name = 'Course Enquiry' AND field_value = '$email_id' ");
      ?>

      <td><?php echo $used; ?></td>
      <td class="<?php if ($number_of_enquiries == $used) echo 'red'; ?>"><?php if ($number_of_enquiries == $used) expired(); rto_deactivation(); ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Why are you passing `false` into `update_field` for the post_id?

Comment: to update the current post. 
Ref: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't got the call to rto_deactivation inside the if condition in the following code:

```
<td class="<?php if ($number_of_enquiries == $used) echo 'red'; ?>">
   <?php if ($number_of_enquiries == $used) expired(); rto_deactivation(); ?>
</td>
```

You don't have any braces around the lines to call when the `if` condition is met:

```
if ($number_of_enquiries == $used) expired(); rto_deactivation();
```

...so `expired();` is only getting called when the condition is met, but rto_deactivation is always going to be executed.

Just change the 'if' to this:

```
if ($number_of_enquiries == $used) { expired(); rto_deactivation(); }
```